# Spread a column of factors by count of factor

Tags: r

Sorry if this is a simple question.

if I have a dataframe that has an ID column and then an Observation column (containing say 'Good' and 'Bad'), with multiple observations per ID..

How can I get r to spread the observation into two columns Good and Bad, with counts of the observations in each column?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `table(df1)`

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: df is the data.frame.

```
table(df$Observation)
```

If you want to calculate count of observation per ID, then:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[ ,table(Observation), by= ID]
```